# Java - I need to print this string of characters to a string I can use out of loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have been buried in this assignment for 2 days chasing down rabbit holes for possible solutions.  I am beginner Java, so I am sure this shouldn't be as difficult as I am making it.

I trying to program the infamous Java Bean Machine...  My professor want the Class Path to return a String Variable that only holds "R" "L" .  to represent the path of the dropped ball.

Each ball should have its own Path...  I can get the path... but I can not get the path to print in a string outside of the for/if statement.

Here are his instructions... in case you can see if I am interpreting this incorrectly.

Please help!!  Thank you in advance for sifting through this....

my code so far ******** i have updated the code to reflect the suggestions..  Thank you...  *****************  New problem is it repeats the series of letters in a line... I only need a string of 6 char ....(LRLLRL)

```
public class Path {
    StringBuilder myPath;

    public Path() {
        myPath = new StringBuilder();

    }

    void moveRight() {

        myPath.append("R");

    }

    void moveLeft() {
        myPath.append("L");

    }

    public void fallLevels(int levels) {

        levels = 6;

        for (int i = 0; i < (levels); i++) {

            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                this.moveRight();

            } else {
                this.moveLeft();

            }

        }

    }
public String getPath() {

    System.out.print(myPath.toString());

    return myPath.toString();

}
```

}

}
        ******Thank you all.. this class now returns the correct string for one ball...***************

here is my code so far for multiple balls... I can get a long continuous string of 6 character sequences... I need each sequence to be a searchable string...I am not sure if I need to alter the Path class or if its something in the simulateGame() method. I think I can take it after this hump... Thank you again....

```
public class BeanMachine {
int numberOfLevels;
int[] ballsInBins;
Path thePath = new Path();

public BeanMachine(int numberOfLevels) {
    this.numberOfLevels = 6;
    ballsInBins = new int[this.numberOfLevels + 1];
    // this.numberOfLevels +
}

public void simulateGame(int number) {



    //looping through each ball
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLevels -1; i++) {
    thePath.fallLevels(0);


        } 
thePath.getPath().toString();

        }
```

*** this isn't the entire code for this class... I have to get this method correct to continue....

Comment: Append to `loop` (instead of resetting it with each iteration of the loop). `loop += "R";` *or* `loop += "L"`. The rest of your code (outside the method containing the loop) doesn't actually appear to do anything.

Comment: lol, I know....  I feel like I am just making my code worse with my trial and error.

Comment: Ok,  so I need a StringBuilder to append items.. correct?  Also, maybe I could post his directions... I think I am getting caught on why I need moveRight and what it should  do....

Comment: Performing `String` concatenation with `loop = loop + "R";` *or* `loop += "R";` uses a `StringBuilder` internally. But **yes**, it would be more efficient to use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Yes you need a `StringBuilder` to append Strings, but you can't access your `loop` variable outside the method `fallLevels` unless you make `loop` an class variable or you return `loop` in the method.

Comment: so sorry, its my first time using this site to comment, and I keep hitting enter... here are the instructions.. maybe it will shed some light onto my madness... Thank you very much....

Comment: The Problem Statement ‐ Path
Start by creating a class named Path.  This class will need to keep up with a single String variable which 
will hold a series of characters the will represent the path the ball takes as it falls through the machine.  
The only possible characters here are "L" or "R", depending on whether the ball fell to the left or right 
when it hit the peg, respectively.  For example, in the example shown above, the String would end up 
being, "LLRRLLR".  Note that because there are 7 levels in this machine, there are exactly 7 characters,

Comment:  A 0‐parameter constructor.  Recall that the purpose of the constructor is to initialize the 
instance variable(s). 
 void moveRight() –
void moveLeft() – This method that will mark that the ball went to the left when it hit a 
peg. 
 void fallLevels(int number) – This method simulate and log the ball falling down the 
specified number of levels.  Remember that at each level there is an equal chance of falling 
either right or left (Hint: use Math.random) 
 String getPath() – This method that will return the String representation of the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your code:

```
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                **loop = this.myPath = "R";**
            } else {
                 **loop = this.myPath ="L";**

            }
```

Change this to:

```
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                **loop = this.myPath + "R";**
            } else {
                 **loop = this.myPath + "L";**

            }
```

Just added ** to highlight where there is wrong in your code

Comment: Thank you for your time and help.   I have revamped my code, he wants us to call methods moveRight and Left... so I have tried to call them in the loop.

Comment: If the above answers your question, please accept it as answer or if it has helped you cast an up vote. Good Luck with your assignment

Comment: I did mark it, but because i am new, it won't let me upvote your response..... I am very grateful.

Comment: Keep Coding.. Good Luck